# Redirecting http requests to https with Node.js, Express, and Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, https

I have deployed my app to heroku, and I am using their ACM. When I go specifically 
to https://www.example.com I have a secure version of my site. But when i just type in www.example.com (which is what a consumer would do) I have the unsecured version of my site.

I want to redirect all http requests to https so the consumer will alway interact with the secure version of the app.

Solutions I have tried so far, which haven't been successful for me are:

1. heroku-ssl-redirect.
2. Using an if statement that checks the X-Forwarded-Proto Header to see if it isn't https and then use a redirect, but no luck with this yet. I am unable to actually see this header when I check in the dev tools for it, So I am wondering if this is the cause of that code not working.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: This works for me: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/7cc8488afcb324eb373c0d014888568ba713925b/server/middleware.js#L3, https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/7cc8488afcb324eb373c0d014888568ba713925b/server/app.js#L19. See it in action: http://starter-kit-ci.herokuapp.com/